# How to change the class of an <i> tag on click? jQuery?

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

This is my <i> class:

```
<i class="button fa fa-heart-o"></i>
```

Note that I am using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)

How do I make it so that when the user clicks on it, the class *"fa-heart-o"* gets replaced with *"fa-heart"*.

I am aware of the toggleClass function in jQuery, along with the addClass function but the problem is that the class *"fa-heart-o"* does not get removed when the user clicks on the item.

**This is what I want the code to output like:**

```
<i class="button fa fa-heart-o"></i>
```

**When the user clicks on it, it becomes:**

```
<i class="button fa fa-heart"></i>
```

**When the user clicks on it again, it becomes:**

```
<i class="button fa fa-heart-o"></i>
```

And so on,

Comment: You may use this `$("#td_id").attr('class', 'newClass');` inside onclick() event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('i.button').click(function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('fa-heart-o')) {
        $this.removeClass('fa-heart-o');
        $this.addClass('fa-heart');
    } else {
        $this.removeClass('fa-heart');
        $this.addClass('fa-heart-o');
    }
});
```

**UPD**
Here is more simpler solution

```
$('i.button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart fa-heart-o');
});
```

Comment: You can use the addclass on the removeclass. `$this.removeClass('fa-heart-o').addClass('fa-heart');`

Comment: or just `$(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');` and you can replace 8 rows of code with just one.